# how to deal with column name occurs twice in the by group in SAS transpose

Tags: sas, transpose, proc

I have a table with account numbers and their attributes. each account has 5 occurring attributes, as such:

```
acc | att1 | att2 | att3 | att4 | att5
```

so I used this code to allow SAS to work with same column names:

```
DATA Final_Sorted_1 ;
    SET Final_Sorted;
    BY mis_division_id mis_wing_id region_id account_branch_id branch_name Attribute ;
    iF first.attribute THEN sequence = 1 ;
    ELSE sequence + 1 ;
RUN ;
```

Then, I am trying to use proc transpose, but I always get the error:

```
The ID value "'16137-בקרת פעילות בחשבונות מבוגר'n" occurs twice in the same BY group.
```

I hope it's well put and understandable:

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=WORK.Final_Sorted_1 
    OUT=WORK.Final_transposed ;
    BY mis_division_id mis_wing_id region_id account_branch_id branch_name ;
    ID Attribute sequence ;
    VAR acc ;
RUN ;
```

Comment: It helps if you (1) simplify your example by working with only one by variable and (2) create some sample data and give that to us too.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to create variable names that are too long. Names are limited to a maximum of 32 bytes. What type of variable is ATTRIBUTE? If character what is the max length the variable can hold? And what is the maximum length in your actual data?

Comment: exactly 32. please check the error. since my column name is in hebrew, it requires ' 'n. Do they count as well? is the column '16137-בקרת פעילות בחשבונות מבוגר'n 32 bits long or 34 ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to show some sample data.

This example exhibits no problems, and yours should neither based on the `data` step you show.

```
data have;
  do l1 = 1 to 3;
  do l2 = 1 to 4;
  do l3 = 1 to 3;
  do l4 = 1 to 2;
  do l5 = 1 to 5;
    do seq = 1 to 5;
      attr='att';
      acc+1;
      output;
    end;
  end;end;end;end; end;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want;
  by l1 l2 l3 l4 l5;
  id attr seq;
  var acc;
run;
```

[image]

pivots to

[image]